# rigidbody.moveposition is not working while using touchphase In unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, rigid-bodies

I'm working on a 3d game for mobile, so I added a script that moves the player by dragging it with one finger.so I tried to make him collide with other objects with different methods but I failed to make him collide. so how to make him collide with objects?

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            targetPosition += Vector3.right * touch.deltaPosition.x * speedmodifier;
            targetPosition += Vector3.forward * touch.deltaPosition.y * speedmodifier;
        }
    }
}
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.MovePosition(targetPosition);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Rigidbody.MovePosition. The Rigidbody.MovePosition is like Transform.Translate. It overrides any collision. An alternative way that you could use is just adding some force (Rigidbody.AddForce) and then add a limit on the maximum speed. That worked for me. Just out of curiosity, when you disable the touchphase, does it collide? I believe not but still... Anyway, the answer to your question is to just not use Rigidbody.MovePosition since it overrides any collision detection.

Comment: how to do it cuz I did it with two different methods using rb.addforce but my player stopped moving.

Comment: Use a variable called max speed. Then calculate the momentum using Transform. After that, use a function that stops the addforce.